# Run two commands with the same argument, on one line

Tags: shell, freebsd, xargs, su

I need to parse a file line by line and pass a value found in them to 2 commands, in FreeBSD's `sh` (no other shells can be used).

My plan was to use `xargs` and `su`:

```
whatever_outputs_values | xargs -I {} su `whoami` -c "cmd1 {}; cmd2 {}"
```

because in FreeBSD `su` does not require a password when used for the same user. This executes in terminal just fine and produces correct results, though slow. But I have to run this in a program code, and this command hangs. I am 99% positive that it hangs because, due to circumstances of which I have no visibility, the SSH library causes it to wait for password input. Due to that, I am looking for an alternative to `su` `whoami`, which is guaranteed to not wait for a password. It probably could be a `for` loop, but coming from Linux `bash` background I fail to devise a working `for` loop for `sh`.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use `su` for this but `sh -c`.  This would make it portable and probably a bit faster.  I would also avoid injecting the output of your left-hand-side command *as code* into the shell command on the right (this is a code injection vulnerability).

```bash
some-command | xargs -I {} sh -c 'cmd1 "$1"; cmd2 "$1"' sh {}
```

This calls an in-line `sh -c` script multiple times with a single argument each time.  The argument is used in a call to `cmd1` and `cmd2`.

The `sh` argument is a "dummy" argument that will be passed to `$0` inside the in-line script.  This is supposed to be the name of the script or shell, and it will be used in any error messages that the shell produces (as when a command can't be found etc.)